# Validate form input then initiate ajax request in single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a form which is to be validated to ensure that all required areas are completed and then either reject request with message to show why or submit the form...

The rejection works fine, it tells the user what information they need after a single button click.

However, If all of the fields are filled in correctly, the form requires 2 clicks of the button to submit.

It appears as though the first click validates and the second click then submits the form. Ideally, I would like everything to be done on one button click

My jQuery

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $form =  $("form[name='pdf-download']"),
    $successMsg = $(".alert");
    $.validator.addMethod("letters", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/);
    });
    $form.validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                letters: true
            },
            email_id: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messagess: {
            firstname: "Please specify your name (only letters and spaces are allowed)",
            email_id: "Please specify a valid email address"
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            $ = jQuery;

            $( "#pdfsubmit" ).click(function() {
                alert("Submitted");
                sendToServer();
            });

            function sendToServer() {

                console.log("#pdfsubmit clicked");
                var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

                pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById("product_sheet"), function() {

                    ps_filename = "generated-product-sheet";
                    var file = btoa(pdf.output());

                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('data', file);

                    $.ajax({
                      url: jspod.ajax_url+'?action=so56917978_upload',
                      data: formData,
                      processData: false,
                      contentType: false,
                      type: 'POST',
                      success: function(data){
                          alert(data);
                      }
                  });
                });
            }
        }
    });  
});
```

If anyone could help me sort the code so that one click does everything that would be much appreciated :-)

Also, I have a signature box on the form.Currently I have no validation for that. If someone could help me add a validation to signature box I would also really appreciate that.

The signature pad

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 sig">
                    <h3>Click to sign</h3>
                    <input type="text" id="pdftxt" name="signature" style="border-radius: 5px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have jQuery attributed to the signature, I can add that also if needed but there is quite a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra `click` listener and the process flow is adding it at the wrong time.

Replace

```
$( "#pdfsubmit" ).click(function() {
    alert("Submitted");
    sendToServer();
});
```

With

```
sendToServer();
```

Comment: I get the same error as with the other answer on here. on click, the page does not submit the form but instead redirects to homepage

Comment: Ok...then that is likely due to an error thrown in console

Comment: when it refreshesto homepage consol reads:  `POD.js?ver=1.1:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (POD.js?ver=1.1:4)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)`

Comment: Sounds like validation plugin missing

Comment: The validation works fine. The form validates as it should. it seems to be an error with submitting the form

Comment: Try adding `debug:true` . Will prevent the submit and see if errors occur in `submitHndler`

Comment: As soon as I load the page and check consol it already says `#pdf submitted` and I get the `alert(data)` response. So removing the onclick function seems to be activating the ajax request on page load and then submitting the form takes me to homepage. I put `debug:true` un but didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

There a several things wrong here : declaring a function `sendToServer()` in submitHandler, and re-adding a click handler. Also, the `$ = jQuery` is pretty strange. Here is a more cleaner implementation

```
jQuery(function($){

    // Declare your function on page load
    function sendToServer() {

        console.log("#pdfsubmit clicked");
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

        pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById("product_sheet"), function() {

            ps_filename = "generated-product-sheet";
            var file = btoa(pdf.output());

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('data', file);

            $.ajax({
              url: jspod.ajax_url+'?action=so56917978_upload',
              data: formData,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              type: 'POST',
              success: function(data){
                  alert(data);
              }
          });
        });
    }

    var $form =  $("form[name='pdf-download']"),
    $successMsg = $(".alert");
    $.validator.addMethod("letters", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/);
    });
    $form.validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                letters: true
            },
            email_id: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messagess: {
            firstname: "Please specify your name (only letters and spaces are allowed)",
            email_id: "Please specify a valid email address"
        },
        // call sendToServer function
        submitHandler: sendToServer()
    });  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried changing the JS to this... when I click submit with an empty form, it performs the validation as required, however when I fill out the form and press submit it seems to cause an error and sends me to the homepage without submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the start from `jQuery(function($){` to `jQuery( "#pdfsubmit" ).click(function() {`

and also `submitHandler: function() {
            $ = jQuery;

```
        $( "#pdfsubmit" ).click(function() {
            alert("Submitted");
            sendToServer();
        });

        function sendToServer() {`
```

to

`submitHandler: function sendToServer() {`

the complete code:

```
jQuery( "#pdfsubmit" ).click(function() {
    var $form = $("form[name='pdf-download']"),
        $successMsg = $(".alert");
        $.validator.addMethod("letters", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/);
    });
    $form.validate({    
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3,
                letters: true
            },
            email_id: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messagess: {
            firstname: "Please specify your name (only letters and spaces are allowed)",
            email_id: "Please specify a valid email address"
        },
        submitHandler: function sendToServer() {

            console.log("#pdfsubmit clicked");
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

            pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById("product_sheet"), function() {

                var file = btoa(pdf.output());

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('data', file);

                $.ajax({
                    url: jspod.ajax_url + '?action=so56917978_upload',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```